# NUXT2 modal component over the layout with dedicated routing

Tags: modal-dialog, nuxt.js, vue-router

One week that i am trying to add a modal for authentification all over the pages with a dedicated route without success.

I achieved to add a modal with hide-overlay above the main pages independently of the actual route... But impossible to add a specific route for this modal !

Indeed, if I use , the page will not be recognised, as 'login' is a component and not a page.

In the example bellow, the dialogSignIn component is placed directly in the default layout :

Picture can told better than me.

[image: The modal dialog is OK, the route is OK, but NUXT tries to push a route...]

[image: This is the home page (for example)]

I tried to add the login component as a custom login layout but layouts are not rendering simultaneously !
I also tried to had the component as a page of nuxtChild page... But we loose the ability to have the component over all the pages (that is the example in the pictures above)

I was expecting the modal to be all aver the pages with it's dedicated route '/login' accessible from everywhere in the website and keeping the actual page behind the hidden overlay.